# Have to create a table with nested section in Angular

Tags: html, angular, user-interface, angular-material, angular-material-table

[Expected Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKNLq.png).  I would like to create a table with in a table as like below picture. please help to achieve a solution for this . i dont know how to proceed. Thanks in advance

I tried by using row span and some examples from internet but unable to achieve this structure.

Comment: please share the code you have tried and if possible a stackblitz!

Answer (score 0):

> 

For a similar problem, i used Bootstrap Grid System to achieve the output,

for reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="complete-table">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1">Name</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">Age</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">FirstName:John</div>
    </div>
    <div class="list">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">1. John Antony</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">19</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">2. John Bob</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">29</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">FirstName:John</div>
    </div>
    <div class="list">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">1. John Antony</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">19</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">2. John Bob</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">29</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```